# Using Immutable JS and Redux - action is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am using `Redux` and `Immutable JS`.
I set up the store like this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

...
const rootReducer = combineReducers({});    
import { initialState } from '../reducers/...';

export const store = createStore(
    combineReducers(rootReducer, initialState),
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )
);
```

Now I get the following error

```
// reducers/.../initialState.js

export function foo(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
     ...
...
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

and it highlights `switch (action.type) {`.

When I am not using `redux-immutable` and set up my store like this

```
import { ..., combineReducers } from 'redux';    

export const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({ initialState }),
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )
);
```

I do not get an error. I do not understand why it says that `action.type` is `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: no it i saying `action` is undefined.

Comment: its action thats undefined not action.type. And i think that combineReducers() function takes an object of reducers, i am not sure you can pass initial state there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineReducers` only takes reducers:

```
const yourRootReducer = combineReducers({ someReducer, someOtherReducer })
```

It [doesn't take](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) `initialState`, your individual stores can (and `createStore` though you usually don't need to there).

Your call to createStore should be:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState, // can be undefined
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  )
);
```

Assuming middleware is an array.

Comment: In `const store = createStore(...` you use `yourRootRecuer`, the one you created with `combineReducers(...`, not `rootReducer`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look like this

```
export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )
);
// I removed the combineReducers()
```

---

Reference: https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable#usage

Example:

```
import {
  combineReducers
} from 'redux-immutable';

import {
  createStore
} from 'redux';

const initialState = Immutable.Map();
const rootReducer = combineReducers({});  // we use the combineReducers() here
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState); // and don't need to use it here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialState` should not be a Reducer.
You should only combine all your Reducers.

Your initial State should be an `object` (State).

**e.g.**

```
{
 loaded: true,
 someDataString: ''
}
```